# d3-sankey-diagram align links by type

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to use the excellent [d3-sankey-diagram](https://github.com/ricklupton/d3-sankey-diagram) library by Rick Lupton to draw a sankey diagram. On the [demo page](https://ricklupton.github.io/d3-sankey-diagram/)  "alignLinkTypes" is used to align links with the same types over nodes, but since November 2017 this keyword does not work any more; https://github.com/ricklupton/d3-sankey-diagram/commits/master/src/sankeyLayout/link-ordering.js. However, it's supposed to be possible to accomplish the same thing using ports.

I've tried to search the readme, the wiki and the source code for an answer, but I haven't found one yet.

Can someone tell me how to align link types like in the demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glad you're finding the library useful! (I'm the author)

Unfortunately, as you've spotted, the demo page is out of date. [Here is an example](https://github.com/ricklupton/ipysankeywidget/blob/master/js/lib/sankey-widget.js#L52-L58) of using the new API (with "ports", which is a more flexible way of controlling alignment) in [ipysankeywidget](https://github.com/ricklupton/ipysankeywidget):

```js
function alignLinkTypes(layout, align) {
  return layout
    .sourceId(function(d) { return { id: typeof d.source === "object" ? d.source.id : d.source,
                                     port: align ? d.type : null }; })
    .targetId(function(d) { return { id: typeof d.target === "object" ? d.target.id : d.target,
                                     port: align ? d.type : null }; });
}
```

If `align` is true, this tells the layout to consider both the `source` and `type` of the link when identifying its start and end points (the old "alignLinkTypes" behaviour); otherwise only the `source` and `target` are considered.

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm! Thanks a lot and continue the fabulous work.